# Faster way to create linked list of length n in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm attempting to create a linked list of length n using Python. I have the simple list implemented, a working concatenation function, and a working create_list function; however, I just want to know if there is a more efficient method at making the linked list than using my concatenate function (made for testing).

Simple List Class:

```
class Cell:

    def __init__( self, data, next = None ):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Concatenate Function:

```
def list_concat(A, B):
    current = A
    while current.next != None:
        current = current.next
    current.next = B
    return A
```

List create (that takes forever!):

```
def create_list(n):
    a = cell.Cell(0)
    for i in (range(1,n)):
        b = cell.Cell(i)
        new_list = cell.list_concat(a, b)   
    return new_list
```

This is an assignment, but efficiency is not part of it. I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way to create a large list using this implementation of the structure.

Comment: do you really need a linked list?

Comment: Comparisons with None are best done based on identity (since None is a singleton), so `while current.next is not None` will suffice. Given that `Cell` has no defined boolean truthness, it is as object "always True" and you could reduce the while loop to `while current.next`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current algorithm has a failure in using the `list_concat` during list creation. The `list_concat` function walks to the end of the list for each node you want to add. So adding a node becomes O(n). This means creating a list of 10,000 items takes 1+2+3...+10,000 steps. That's O(n*n) performance.

As hinted, you should add the next node in the creation loop. You then get code that looks like this (I left out the `list_concat` function as it's not used):

```
class Cell(object):
  def __init__(self, data, next=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

def create_list(length=1):
  linked_list = Cell(0)
  head = linked_list
  for prefill_value in xrange(1, length):
    head.next = Cell(prefill_value)
    head = head.next
  return linked_list
```

You could also create the list in reverse order, allowing you to immediately fill the `next` attribute of the Cell. Your create_list function then looks like this (the `reversed` function should not be used for really huge lengths (several million) because it's created in-memory):

```
def create_list(length=1):
  tail = Cell(length - 1)
  for prefill_value in xrange(length - 2, -1, -1):
    tail = Cell(prefill_value, tail)
  return tail
```

Comment: Of course, if you don't need the values of the `Cells` to be increasing the `xrange` statement could be drastically simplified. This would make the second, reverse, `create_list` function a lot easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign to the previous node's `next` attribute directly in the loop:

```
def create_list(n):
    for i in range(n):
        c = cell.Cell(n)
        if i == 0:
            lst = c
        else:
            prev.next = c
        prev = c
    return lst
```

Comment: Do you propose to test i==0 at every step of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_list(n):
    a = cell.Cell(0)
    for i in (range(1,n)):
```

You don't need the parens around `range(1,n)`

```
        b = cell.Cell(i)
        new_list = cell.list_concat(a, b)   
    return new_list
```

It'll be faster if you build the list in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_concat(A, B):
    current = A
    while current.next != None:
        current = current.next
    current.next = B
    # Why 'return A' when the caller already gave A?
```

Aside from adding a function that implimented `list_concat` for arrays, you could just make a simple edit to create_list:

```
def create_list(n):
    a = cell.Cell(0)
    for i in (range(1,n)):
        b = cell.Cell(i)
        cell.list_concat(a, b)   
        a = b 
    return a
```

Now, every time list_concat runs, it starts at the end of the list and just appends b.

I'd recomend, over the above, writing a class that held the first and last nodes in the list. That way, it'd be as simple as

```
def create_list(n):
    list = List()
    for x in range( 0, n ):
        list.put_at_end( Cell(x) ) # or list.append_cell(x)
```